# Why has the feld become undefined?

Tags: javascript

I attempted to building a class for a slider but when I try to use its feld they are undefined

```js
class Slider {
    constructor() {
        this.nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
        this.previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
        this.imageDivs =document.querySelectorAll(".img-continer .img");
        this.index = 0;
    }

    SlideNext() {
        console.log(this.imageDivs); //the output is undefined;
        this.index++;
    }

    SlidePrevious() {
    
    }

    init() {
        this.nextButton.addEventListener("click" , this.SlideNext);
        this.previousButton.addEventListener("click", this.SlidePrevious);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML since the field in question is reading from the HTML? `this.imageDivs =document.querySelectorAll(".img-continer .img");`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rx3fu24z/2/

Comment: Are you waiting for `window.onload` to ensure that your HTML contents are available in the DOM? Are `nextButton` and `previousButton` also logging as "undefined"?

Comment: nextButton and previousButton aren't undefined

Comment: the problem was in this context when I send the function as a call back I needed to bind its to the current context the code `this.nextButton.addEventListener("click" , this.SlideNext.bind(this));` fix the problem